# Visual Basic button.click how to return to If

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem, I want the program after pressing the button to check if there are files in different locations (I used if), and if this file not exists, I would download them (else) and that after downloading I would go back to if and continue the rest of the code.

```
If ComboBox2.SelectedItem = "1.12.2 Release" Then
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(natives & "\1.12.2\natives") Then
        launch = ("START CODE")
        Shell("cmd.exe @echo off /c" & launch)
        Me.Close()
    Else
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("MY URL/natives.zip", natives & "\1.12.2\natives.zip")
        System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(natives & "\1.12.2\natives.zip", natives & "\1.12.2")
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(natives & "\1.12.2\natives.zip")
        Return
```

I want to add much more to this code, and I want first do this and I stayed here.
In code I can see just one of maybe 5-7 folders to check

Comment: Are you saying that you want to jump back to the "if ComboBox2.SelectedItem=..." instead of "Return"?  I assume you want to avoid the use of "Goto" at all costs.  Since the program is closing anyway, can't you use a simple "while true do" and replace your return with "continue"

Comment: Exceeded five minutes and loaded up VB to check syntax (I rely too heavily on the IDE to help me out).  VB.NET format is actually "while true", without the "do", and ended with "end while".  To continue, it isn't "continue" but instead it is "continue while".

Comment: Do it the other way round: if the directory does not exist, obtain the files. Launch the program after the End If.

Comment: How exactly it must look like to return
And i will check later replace it to diretcory does not exist

Comment: There is no return. To make it fit in this comment box, I have omitted some of the code: `If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.... Then` `My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile...` `End If` `launch = ("START CODE")...`.

Answer (score 1):

Create following logic

```
sub Main()
    if not CheckFolders() then
        if not DownloadFolders() then
            MessageBox.Show("Can't start program")
            Return
        end if
    end if

    ' Start your program here
end sub


function CheckFolders() as boolean
    ' check your folders here
end function

function DownloadFolders() as boolean
    ' download your folders here
end function
```

This way you separate logic of checking for files/folders from downloading and startup logic. And you can manipulate each separate component the way you want

Comment: i want to check this folder and download after pressing the button

Comment: This is a vb.net with a c# flavor mate :)

Comment: @JQSOFT it looks fine in an online editor. VB is not case sensitive  and this  text editor has no syntax corrector :)

Comment: @RomekPable use what I have in `Main` in your `onClick` event. Rename identifiers to your liking. I gave you the principal logic. Also, you can use `File.Exists` or `Directory.Exists` instead of  `My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists`.